# How to find the location of missing values in the data set in R?

Tags: r, missing-data

Is there any function to indicate the location of missing values in R?

Comment: You can use a simple filter, like this: `df[is.na(df$yourcolumn),]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If df is the name of your dataframe them `which(is.na(df))`

Answer (score -1):

Yes - use the `is.na()` function.  There are some examples in the [R documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/NA), but basically it returns a boolean value.